# Fluent NHibernate C#. How I can use table model(entity)and her Map class from two different assemblies?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

How I can use table model(entity)and her Map class from two different assemblies?
If I put map class in model's assembly, everything OK, but i need to use different assemblies for onion architecture.
My entity class:

```
public partial class SP_Quarters   
{
    public virtual  int id { get; set; }
    public virtual Nullable<byte> active { get; set; }
    public virtual string name0_ru { get; set; }
    public virtual string name0_uz { get; set; }

}
```

Map class:

```
public SP_QuartersMap()
    {
   Id(x => x.id);
   Map(x => x.active);
   Map(x => x.name0_ru);
   Map(x => x.name0_uz);

    }
```

And session factory:

```
public ISession OpenSession()
    {

        ISessionFactory sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()

            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2012.ConnectionString(ConnectionString))
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<SP_Quarters>())
            .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaUpdate(cfg).Execute(false, true))
            .BuildSessionFactory();
             return sessionFactory.OpenSession();
```

}

---

**Solution**

```
 public ISession OpenSession()
    {
            ISessionFactory sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2012.ConnectionString(ConnectionString))
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<SP_Quarters>().Add<SP_QuartersMap>())
                  .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaUpdate(cfg).Execute(false, true))
            .BuildSessionFactory();

        return sessionFactory.OpenSession();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public ISession OpenSession()
{
        ISessionFactory sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
        .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2012.ConnectionString(ConnectionString))
        .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<SP_Quarters>().Add<SP_QuartersMap>())
              .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaUpdate(cfg).Execute(false, true))
        .BuildSessionFactory();

    return sessionFactory.OpenSession();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell FluentNHibernate which assemblies to *load mappings from*. The mapping themselves points to the assemblies containing entity classes using the normal assebly reference system as any compiled .Net-code would.

`m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<T>()` specifies which assembly to get the *mappings* from. There is no requirement to specify `T` as one of you entity classes.

Also, `AddFromAssemblyOf)` is itself just a convenience method, there are other ways to locate the mapping assemblies.

Comment: Thank you for feedback, I just used .Add (  .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<MedicalProductsInPharmacy>().Add<MedicalProductsInPharmacyMap>()))

Comment: @ViktorNovikov Great. If you feel that this answered your question, please mark this as the accepted answer.